# Architecture for application that searches metadata

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I need to create an application to search for image, video and text files stored in Google Cloud Storage based on their metadata. For example, when the user performs a car search in the application, it should query all files stored in Google Cloud Storage, read its metadata, and return only the files that match the search.

I am thinking of using the following architecture:

**Cloud Storage** to store files and metadata
**App Engine** to host the Java application

But I'm still not sure if this architecture is the most appropriate. I'm also not sure about the process to fetch the files in Cloud Storage and then read their metadata. This seems to me that it will greatly impact the performance of the application.

Has anyone had experience on a similar project and could share some tips?

Thank you.

Comment: Alex Smith: I'd store the metadata somewhere else that's faster to query - either Datastore or Memorystore / Redis would be a good option. Then your App Engine app can query that and fetch identifiers to the Cloud Storage objects that need to be returned.
How up to date does your app need to be? You could either run a batch job (every hour, day, week etc.) to update the metadata store or if it's critical to be in real-time then use a Cloud Function to update it as an object is uploaded to Cloud Storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your choice, you can choose between App Engine Standard o Flexible, I would like to add that the App Engine Standard manages Java 8, if you want a different runtime, you can choose App Engine Flexible, and Cloud Storage is the correct choice if some images are managed in the App.